# Execute SQL script on docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a project that runs when ./entrypoint.sh or docker-compose up is run from the root directory of project and generates the swagger API interface, but the calls return entry response no data.

If I run with MySQL on localhost without docker, works perfectly fine. How do I load the data?

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

docker network create turingmysql
docker container run -p  3306:3306 --name mysqldb --network turingmysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=tshirtshop -d mysql:5.7
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

DockerFile

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ADD ./database/tshirtshop.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

```
#### Stage 1: Build the application
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build

# Set the current working directory inside the image
WORKDIR /app

# Copy maven executable to the image
COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn

# Copy the pom.xml file
COPY pom.xml .

# Build all the dependencies in preparation to go offline. 
# This is a separate step so the dependencies will be cached unless 
# the pom.xml file has changed.
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline -B

# Copy the project source
COPY src src


# Package the application
RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

#### Stage 2: A minimal docker image with command to run the app 
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ARG DEPENDENCY=/app/target/dependency

# Copy project dependencies from the build stage
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.turing.ecommerce.TuringApplication"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

# Define services
services:
  # App backend service
  app-server:
    # Configuration for building the docker image for the backend service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # Forward the exposed port 8080 on the container to port 8080 on the host machine
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - mysqldb # This service depends on mysql. Start that first.
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/tshirtshop?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root   
    networks: # Networks to join (Services on the same network can communicate with each other using their name)
      - turingmysql

      # Database Service (Mysql)
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always

    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: tshirtshop
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

    networks:
      - turingmysql  


# Volumes
volumes:
  db-data:

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  turingmysql:
```

Comment: Well, is `tshirtshop.sql` inserting any values to the database? Is your application properly configured to query the database and not return empty results?

Comment: Yes, lots of create table and insert statements.

Comment: Have you inserted log statements into the API to verify things *should* be returned?

Comment: If I run without docker, the API calls return data. I have deployed on [heroku](https://backend-turing-ecommerce.herokuapp.com/swagger-ui.html#/) where I created the database separately and deployed and it works but I am required to dockerize it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have two Dockerfiles? Looks like you built your own MySQL container?

Otherwise, these shouldn't be part of your **Java** multi-stage build

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ADD ./database/tshirtshop.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

---

Assuming that you did build a separate image for mysql, in the Docker-Compose, you're not using it, as you're still referring to `image: mysql:5.7`

Rather than building your own, you should mount the SQL script into it

For example

```
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ...
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./database/tshirtshop.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0_init.sql
```

Then, forget the Java service for a minute and use MySQL workbench or the mysql CLI to verify that data is actually there. Once you do, then startup the API

Comment: I have only one dockerfile. I have removed those two lines and tried to mount, no respite.

Comment: If you do `docker-compose logs mysqldb`, do you see it running the script?

Comment: `docker-compose rm -sf mysqldb`, then start it up again

Comment: Also, you should remove `docker container run` from your script since you are starting mysql in the docker-compose up command

Answer (score 2):

If you copying `sql` scipt already to docker build then you do not need to mapped it again in the docker-compose, if you have docker-compose then you do not the bash script single command `docker-compose up --build` will do the job.

So modify your docker-compose as per your Dockerfile.

Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql

ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  # App backend service
  app-server:
    # Configuration for building the docker image for the backend service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # Forward the exposed port 8080 on the container to port 8080 on the host machine
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - mysqldb # This service depends on mysql. Start that first.
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/tshirtshop?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root   
    networks: # Networks to join (Services on the same network can communicate with each other using container name)
      - uringmysql

      # Database Service (Mysql)

  mysql:
    build: .
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: appdata
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root123
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    tty: true
# Volumes
volumes:
  db-data:

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  turingmysql:
```

Now just run

```
docker-compose up --build
```

this will build and up the container and you will not need to mapped the host init script, as it already in Docker image.

The directory structure will look like

[image]

Now you application will able to access DB using `jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/tshirtshop?` this endpoint as both are in same network and can refer eacher other using name.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) and [Adii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3288890/adiii) for the responses. They put me in the right direction. I want to document my experience and how the issue was resolved.  New to dockerization so I was learning by practice. For anyone new to dockerization and having same issues in Spring Boot, MySQL and docker, this would surely help

First, my entrypoint.sh changed below. The docker-compose down is for restarts.

```
     #!/bin/bash

docker-compose down -v
docker-compose up --build
```

Second, I had to use an existing mysql image instead of building one.

```
version: '3.7'

# Define services
services:
  # App backend service
  app-server:
    # Configuration for building the docker image for the backend service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # Forward the exposed port 8080 on the container to port 8080 on the host machine
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - mysql # This service depends on mysql. Start that first.
    environment: # Pass environment variables to the service
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/tshirtshop?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: turing
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: pass  
    networks: # Networks to join (Services on the same network can communicate with each other using their name)
      - turingmysql

      # Database Service (Mysql)
  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: tshirtshop
      MYSQL_USER: turing
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass


    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    tty: true
    networks: # Networks to join (Services on the same network can communicate with each other using their name)
      - turingmysql

# Volumes
volumes:
  db-data:

 # Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  turingmysql:
    driver: bridge
```

Needed to specify that the network is a bridge. My sql file was mounted from a folder relative to docker-compose.yml. Also had to add allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true to my  jdbc url. Created a user to access the database tshirtshop.

And here is the Dockerfile.

```
#### Stage 1: Build the application
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build

# Set the current working directory inside the image
WORKDIR /app

# Copy maven executable to the image
COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn

# Copy the pom.xml file
COPY pom.xml .

# Build all the dependencies in preparation to go offline. 
# This is a separate step so the dependencies will be cached unless 
# the pom.xml file has changed.
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline -B

# Copy the project source
COPY src src


# Package the application
RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

#### Stage 2: A minimal docker image with command to run the app 
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ARG DEPENDENCY=/app/target/dependency

# Copy project dependencies from the build stage
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.turing.ecommerce.TuringApplication"]
```

to run, from root directory of project ./entrypoint.sh on mac and the rest is  history.